# Calculate date based on the date in text box

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with few text boxes.

I would like to calculate a date based on the date put on text box1.

E.g. on text box 1 you enter today's date.
I want to calculate a date 5 years from today on textbox 2.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
TextBox2.Value = Format(Val(TextBox1.Value) + 1825, "DD/MM/YYYY")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @BigBen CDate worked, excellent many thank for all your help and prompt respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Use `DateValue` or `CDate` instead of `Val`.
- Use `DateAdd` instead of the hard-coded `1825`.

```
Format(DateAdd("yyyy", 5, CDate(TextBox1.Value)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
TextBox2.Value = Format(CDate(TextBox1.Value) + 1825, "DD/MM/YYYY")
End Sub

Comment: `+ 1825` doesn't handle leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Use DatePicker you deminish chances of incorrect input and amount of needed error handlers and issues when user has US instead of UK format, or the other way around.

For using date use `Dim myDate as Date: myDate = DateSerial(year, month, day)` <- all as integers, whenever handled by code, this also would protect you from format differences.

Never set hard date format into inputs.

Comment: Hi Sorry how Do i now add for days for example 70 days for another textbox?

Comment: do you mean you insert a date and then add a specific number of days to that date? 
If so than it should look like this: `Dim today As Date: today = Date: today = today + 70` just take the value as integer from the textbox and the date from datepicker.

Comment: Hi Kris thanks; i get an FALSE on textbox17 when used below code Private Sub [TextBox16_Change()
Dim today As Date:
TextBox17.Value = today = Date: today = today + 70
End Sub]

Comment: Type it as `Cint(Textbox17)` additionaly make handler to make sure that entry type is actually an integer. something in lines `If Isnumeric(textbox17) then: today = today + cint(textbox17): else MsgBox "Please insert a numeric value` Im not sure right now and im on my phone, but even if inserted value is double it should cut to integer as in C++